# No candidate ver: failed to read mirror file?

Tags: upgrade

What are these `No candidate ver` and `Failed to read mirror file` error when trying to upgrade?

```
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Translation-en
Fetched 29.4 kB in 6s (4877 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
No candidate ver:  belocs-locales-bin
No candidate ver:  libbind9-30
No candidate ver:  libcupsys2
No candidate ver:  libdatrie0
No candidate ver:  libdns35
No candidate ver:  libevent1
No candidate ver:  libisc35
No candidate ver:  libisccc30
No candidate ver:  libisccfg30
No candidate ver:  liblwres30
No candidate ver:  libxcb-xlib0
No candidate ver:  system-services
No candidate ver:  upstart-compat-sysv
No candidate ver:  upstart-logd

Updating repository information
WARNING: Failed to read mirror file
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: Yes. Trying to upgrade from 10 to 12.